# How to find the maximum number of active sessions reached in the last 24 hours in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So I am not so well-versed with `Oracle` so kindly bear with me.

I have used this query to get the current number of active sessions to an oracle database:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION;
```

Now, I want to basically get the maximum number of active sessions to the instance in the last 24 hours, or generally in the last `n` days. 
Could anyone help me out with the query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The required information can be found by querying the `DBA_HIGH_WATER_MARK_STATISTICS` table.

The required `NAME` is `SESSIONS` which gives us the Maximum Number of Concurrent Sessions seen in the database.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3124.htm#G2023397) for more details.

Comment: since instance startup, not of just the last 24 hours, unless of course you restart the instance every day ....